# Is the 'Click to chat' not working anymore on whatssap?

Tags: html, whatsapp

I cannot create a redirect link in whatssap anymore. It seems to no redirect to chat. In my whatssap, this link does not start a new chat with preflilled text.

```
    https://web.whatsapp.com/send?phone=5512 98183-2011&text=oi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few days ago WhatsApp had technical issues on chrome & safari (desktop). It last 1 day to fix it. So, I think it's only temporary. I sent them a hint. Maybe you do too.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it's down or officially removed as a feature, but it's not working for me either. The Click to Chat feature is still listed in the FAQ though.